# How do I prevent a user from being able to type or click in an input field? [React]

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, input

A bit of an odd request, but I'm looking for a way to have an input field be completely un-interactable with.

I have a component with an input field that the user should interact with. In another page of my app, I want to reuse the visual of that component, but they should not be able to interact with it.

I have tried:

```
<input
       type="text"
       placeholder="[Click here to enter scramble you want to solve]"
       onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
/>
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Add a prop for disable the input based on parent component where you want to use

```
<input
       type="text"
       placeholder="[Click here to enter scramble you want to solve]"
       onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
      disabled={props.disabled}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try readonly inside input field, it might work for you

```
<input readonly type="text">
```